# Sinon.JS Command Line Commands

Tags: sinon

I am trying to learn Sinon.JS. I have installed Sinon.JS using npm. Nowhere in the documentation can I find any command line commands. On the sinonjs.org site, there is "documentation" such as this:

```
function once(fn) {
    var returnValue, called = false;
    return function () {
        if (!called) {
            called = true;
            returnValue = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        return returnValue;
    };
}

it('calls the original function', function () {
    var callback = sinon.fake();
    var proxy = once(callback);

    proxy();

    assert(callback.called);
});
```

How do I *run* this test using Sinon.JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) is a library that provides "standalone test spies, stubs, and mocks for JavaScript."

It "works with any unit testing framework."

The key idea is that it is a library that works *within a testing framework*.

It will work with any of the major JavaScript testing frameworks like [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api), [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/), [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), etc.

---

For example, to implement the test from the question using `Sinon` and `Jest` do `npm install --save-dev sinon` to add `Sinon`, then do `npm install --save-dev jest` to add `Jest`, and add a test file (something like `src/code.test.js`) with the following code:

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

function once(fn) {
  var returnValue, called = false;
  return function () {
      if (!called) {
          called = true;
          returnValue = fn.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      return returnValue;
  };
}

it('calls the original function', function () {
  var callback = sinon.fake();
  var proxy = once(callback);

  proxy();

  expect(callback.called).toBe(true);  // SUCCESS
});
```

Note that `assert` on the last line is implemented in this case with the [`expect`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect) assertion from `Jest`.

Then run `Jest` and it will *use* `Sinon` when it runs `code.test.js`.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much.

Comment: I can't find anywhere to "accept" this answer. It may be because I'm too much of a newbie to have that privilege. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @zumafra no worries, I'll help you out: ["To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  You've got the privilege, everyone does (everyone can accept answers to their own questions).  :)

Comment: Ah! Right in front of my nose. Thanks!